# How to copy a file to all subfolders with specific name?

Tags: windows-7, powershell

I have a file called SRED.txt and a folder which contains hundreds of subfolders. In each folder is another folder called SRED where this SRED.txt file should be saved. What I want to do is loop through each folder and copy the SRED.txt file into the corresponding SRED folder.

How can I accomplish this with Powershell?

Answer (score 9):

Get the `SRED` directories recursively, then copy the file for each directory.

```
dir  c:\Projects SRED -Recurse|
    where {$_.PSIsContainer}|
    foreach { copy C:\Path\To\SRED.txt $_.FullName }
```

With the new `-Directory` parameter in PowerShell v3:

```
dir  c:\Projects SRED -Recurse -Directory|
    foreach { copy C:\Path\To\SRED.txt $_.FullName }
```

Comment: I will let you know how it goes.

Comment: There seems to be a problem with the Foreach loop. Do you know of any decent resources for me to help learn this? I'm not sure how the syntax of Powershell goes.

Comment: PowerShell has an excellent built-in help system. To see all of the help for any CmdLet, type `help <CmdLet name> -full`. For Foreach-Object: `help foreach -full`. To see help for additional topics type `help about*` which will give a list of 'about' topics such as `help about_Command_Syntax`. If you hover over the PowerShell tag in your question then click on the 'info' link on the popup, there are some links to resources about PowerShell.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you need something like PS for this. Open a Command Prompt window and navigate (using `cd`) to the top-level folder (which contains all your project folders). Make sure the SRED.txt file is present in this top-level folder. Now run the following command:

```
for /f "delims=" %d in ('dir SRED /ad /b /s') do @xcopy SRED.txt "%d"
```

Comment: I will let you know how its goes.